# Angular and RxJS - catchError() wont catch the request error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**UPDATE: I FOUND THE ISSUE. THE ANSWER IS BELOW**

I have the following code in my service class:

```
public getListById(id:string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get<any[]>(`${BASE_URL.local}/${id}`).pipe(
            map(obj => obj),
            catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
        )
    }

handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
        console.log(error)
        this.snackBar.open(
            "Server Error",
            "X"
        )
        return EMPTY;
    }
```

And the following code in my component:

```
this.myService.getListById(id).subscribe(
    res => { doSomethingWith(res) },
    error => { 
        this.noRows = true
        console.log(error)
    },
    () => { this.loading = false }
)
```

When the service calls GET in the Rest address, it is giving a 500 error and I would like do handle it.

But the `catchError()` function in `pipe()`, for some reason, doesn't catch the error and only runs the `() => { this.loading = false }` code inside `subscribe()`.

What am I doing wrong with this bad RxJs module (seriously, I don't like the way that it works with backend requests) that I can't simply handle a request error?

Thank you.

**ANSWER**

I found the issue. Another previous developer defined an **Error Interceptor** that wasn't working as it should.

I deleted the `ErrorInterceptor` and defined a new one. I also fixed the 'providers' property definition in my `app.module.ts`, it wasn't referencing the correct ErrorInterceptor class as it should.

Comment: Are you seeing the `console.log(error) ` and snackbar from within `handleError`, or nothing at all?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera Nothing. Even if I put a breakpoint in this line.

Comment: Can you return `throwError('outter error').pipe` instead of your `this.http.get.pipe` in the getListById function, for debugging purposes? If your error function runs, it could be that angular doesn't consider your 500 as an actual error.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, your subscribe does not go to `doSomethingWith` either, correct?

Comment: When the server return 500 it does not go to "doSomethingWith". When the server return 200 (ok), it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it catches the error, since the `subscribe`'s **complete** callback is invoked(`() => { this.loading = false }`). This cb is reached because you're returning `EMPTY`, which [immediately completes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L28).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly a sign that the error has been caught by `catchError`.

`handleError` returns `EMPTY` that means to close a stream without an emit. And because the stream has been closed you see `this.loading = false`.

put `debugger` before `console.log(error)` and open developer tools to inspect variables, perhaps `this.snackBar.open` has an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I did that and the debugger simply doesn't stop at the breakpoint, neither if I put a function directly inside the catchError() :/

Comment: Aha, then it means there's another interceptor that does the same, please search in your code, quite sure solution will be almost the same there: `catchError` and `EMPTY`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is different but try to change the behavior like this :

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(`${BASE_URL.local}/${id}`).pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    this.errorObject = err;
    return throwError(err);
  })
);
```

`public errorObject = null;`

by default set the error to null : `this.errorObject = null;`

Comment: Thank OAH for your response. But during the request he simply doesnt even fall in "catchError" funcition. I can't even debug it :/

Comment: remove the catch from service : ```return this.http.get<any[]>(`${BASE_URL.local}/${id}`)``` , then leave your component as it is